# Error transfering the data from GCS to Bigquery using dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to load data from GCS to Bigquery table . i want to create the table on the fly .
Below is the content of file

```
abc,1234,2023-05-10,1,1.5
xyz,2345,2023-05-10,1,1.6
```

Below is the dataflow code which i am trying to execute in local.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients.bigquery import TableSchema

# Define the GCS file path
gcs_file_path = 'gs://gcs_path/table_v1.txt'

# Define the BigQuery table details
project_id = 'project_v1'
dataset_id = 'dataset_v1'
table_id = 'table_v1'
table_schema_str = 'emp_name:STRING,id:INTEGER,temp_date:DATE,contact:INTEGER,dept:FLOAT'

# Define the pipeline options
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

# Define the pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    # Read the CSV file from GCS
    csv_lines = (
        pipeline
        | 'Read CSV' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(gcs_file_path)
    )

    # Parse the CSV lines and convert them to a dictionary
    table_data = (
        csv_lines
        | 'Parse CSV' >> beam.Map(lambda line: dict(zip(table_schema_str.split(','), line.split(','))))
    )

    # Write the table data to BigQuery
    table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
        projectId=project_id,
        datasetId=dataset_id,
        tableId=table_id,
    )
    table_schema = TableSchema()
    for field in table_schema_str.split(','):
        name, type = field.split(':')
        table_schema.fields.append(bigquery.TableFieldSchema(name=name, type=type))

    (
        table_data
        | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table_spec,
            schema=table_schema,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        )
    )
```

Below is the error .It is coming for all the columns

> WARNING:apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery:There were errors inserting to
> BigQuery. Will retry. Errors were [<InsertErrorsValueListEntry
> errors: [<ErrorProto
> debugInfo: ''
> location: 'emp_name:STRING'
> message: 'no such field: emp_name:STRING.'
> reason: 'invalid'>]
> index: 0>]

Comment: Just to be sure: Will your file be always formatted as a CSV?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere.Thanks for response. yes it will always be in CSV format

Comment: So, why do you use Dataflow? Won't be easier to load all the data in bigquery first (load job, free and fast), and them perform a query for the transformation?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere. This  is first step of data loading. further i will include some schema level and data validation also. so i choose to do via dataflow

Comment: You will start to load the data and then perform data validation and schema change/update in bigquery?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere. before loading i want to perform schema and data validation  and then load to big query

Comment: That's a mistake IMO. Forget ETL, think ELT. Load the data in a temporary table in BigQuery, perform the validation that you want and then merge the result in the target table. It's simpler (sql only), faster, cheaper. Dataflow has many other use case, but if you are BigQuery only oriented, go into BigQuery as soon as you can, and then use SQL to perform your stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are encountering in [***ErrorProto***](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/ErrorProto) is generally because of the **invalid** `emp_name` field. Check your CSV input data and **overwrite it on GCS**.

Another workaround is to use `insert_retry_strategy` in ***WriteToBigquery*** transform. The rows with permanent errors will be tagged with **"FailedRows"** by using strategies like **“RETRY_NEVER”** and **“RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR”**. This data can be processed later manually through the tag:

```
 res = pcoll | WriteToBigQuery(...)

 failures = res['FailedRows'] #Processing failed rows after WriteToBigquery step
```

Comment: .Thanks for response . As i am creating the table on the fly, I have provided the schema for same in "table_schema_str" variable .i m not able to understand how column name can be invalid eventhough table is not created . Am i missing something at code level